# How to find maximum and value of column with the same column in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to find maximum value of the `has_sold` column in an specific `province`.For example in all rows with `province = Tehran` which row has the most `has_sold` value?
This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE fp_stores_data_test (
    time INTEGER,
    province VARCHAR(20),
    city VARCHAR(20),
    market_id INTEGER,
    product_id INTEGER,
    price INTEGER, 
    quantity INTEGER,
    has_sold INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (time, city, province, market_id ,product_id)
);
```

I had tried this `SELECT DISTINCT city, max(has_sold) FROM fp_stores_data_test GROUP BY city`, but I'm not sure it's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below one using `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by province order by has_sold desc) as rn
from fp_stores_data_test
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: but this query returns time, I need `product_id`. would you explain more how it works?

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi, could you please add some sample data and your expected output in table format

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres, I would recommend `distinct on` to solve this greatest-n-per-group problem. It is usually more efficient than other alternatives.

```
select distinct on (province) f.*
from fp_stores_data_test f
order by province, has_sold desc
```

For each `province`, this gives you the row that has the greatest `has_sold`. If there are ties, only one row is returned anyway (you can add another sorting criteria to break the ties and make the result deterministic).

If you want to allow potential top ties, then use `rank()` instead:

```
select *
from (
    select f.*, rank() over(partition by province order by has_sold desc) rn
    from fp_stores_data_test f
) f
where rn = 1
```